# Django ModelForm create multiple instances with different ForeignKeys

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

In my Django app I have two models like these:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)

class Bar(models.Model):
    class descr = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I want to have a ModelForm for Foo which is easy enough. However, I want to be able to create multiple `Foo` instances that are individually tied to different `Bar` instances. So, say I had three `Bar` instances, I want to have a model form that, with only one form and on one submission, would create three `Foo` instances, each respectively linking the new `Foo` instances to one of my `Bar` instances.

Basically what I'm doing is making a "Bulk Creation" of Foo. I don't want to use many-to-many because I don't want one Foo object tied to three Bar objects. I want each Bar to have its own unique Foo.

I figured I could use a ModelForm and when I instantiate it, possibly add some references to my Bar instances and then override `save()` on the modelform to create the "duplicate" entries. My modelform would not include the `bar` field since I'd be handling it manually.

Does this seem like the right approach? Any pitfalls? Other design approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not as complicated as you think. In django when you set a object's id to null and save it again, django would create a new instance identical to the first one. So you could do roughly:

```
form = FooForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    new_foo = form.save()
    new_foo.id = None
    # this will create another instance
    new_foo.save()
```

[The doc has a section describes this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances).

There's one pitfall in your approach, you should try to stay away from overriding model/model form `save()` method as much as you can, it will mess up with a lot of things and/or make things complicated. If you want to save something with additional steps on models, use django `pre_save` or `post_save` [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/). If you want to do something with model form, do `obj = form.save(commit=False)` and change the `obj` however you want, then do `obj.save()`.